# Shell comparison not working on Synology

Tags: linux, shell, synology

This is driving me insane. I think it has to do with Synology

This is being ran on a Synology Server.

```
### VARIABLES ###
LOGIF=/volume7/homes/admin/scripts/data/achclean-logi.txt
HOWOLD=$(cat $LOGIF | wc -l)
# END DEFINITIONS


if (( ${HOWOLD} >= 7 )); then
  echo -e "WORKS" >> 
fi
```

I get this error in the terminal: scriptname: line Number: [Value of HOWOLD]: not found

If I run this on Linux, RedHat, it works.

```
HOWOLD=$(cat dfile | wc -l)

if (( ${HOWOLD} >= 2 )); then
   echo "WORKS"
fi
```

EDIT:
NO LUCK!!!!!!!!

```
if [ "$HOWOLD" >= "7" ]; then # if 7, then it's been 7 days!
```

sh: 7: unknown operand

NO LUCK!!!!!!!!

```
if (( "$HOWOLD" >= "7" )); then # if 7, then it's been 7 days!
```

scriptname: line Number: [Value of HOWOLD]: not found

Comment: and  you added a debug statment like `echo "#dbg:HOWOLD=$HOWOLD"` and it printed what? ;-) Good luck.

Comment: Also, if you're using `#!/bin/sh` as your "shebang" line, try using `#!/bin/bash` (or ksh) and see if that helps. Good luck.

Comment: There isn't bash, so I am using sh. I figured it out and will post the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking it's because whatever version of Shell this Synology is using is older then I am use to.

I got it working by using -ge inplace of >=

```
    if [ ${HOWOLD} -ge 7 ];
```

Comment: just FYI, I found this synology is sadly using Ash. /bin/ash